# Are unassigned #defines implicitly assigned to 0?

Tags: c

I came across some compilation switches and there was one thing that surprised me. I couldn't understand why the code compiled even if the defined value was pure trash.

It seems like `#if` automatically assigns the `#define` value to 0 and does not trigger any error, whereas `if` statement does not.

```
#define variable pureGarbage|0xff
#if (variable == 0xff)
#define testVar 1
#endif


int main()
{
    printf("%d", testVar)
    return 0;
}
```

And guess what? It works. Can somebody confirm this with misra standard? Is this the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
#if (pureGarbage == ff)
```

compares two macro-values `pureGarbage` and `ff`, and executes the body

```
#define testVar 1
```

if they are identical. Since you do not set both macros `pureGarbage` and `ff`, they are *both* treated as *zero* , so the condition effectively is

```
#if (0 == 0)
```

which is trivially true, hence the body is executed and `testVar` is defined as `1`.

The first line

```
#define variable pureGarbage|0xff
```

doesn't play any role here.

Comment: sorry, i edited the code. Can you answer again, please? thank you!

Comment: my question is why pureGarbage is treated as 0? and variable gets 0|0xff

Comment: The same principle: undefined macro names used in constant expressions evaluate to 0